# composer require laravel/ui is not working

Tags: laravel

I wanted to make `php artisan make:auth` work in my project but when running the command `composer require laravel/ui` I am facing the following problems(I am on ubuntu OS):

Using version ^1.1 for laravel/ui
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
    - laravel/ui v1.1.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1].
    - laravel/ui v1.1.1 requires illuminate/support ~5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1].
    - illuminate/support v6.5.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v6.5.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v6.4.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v6.3.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v6.2.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v6.1.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v6.0.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v6.0.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v6.0.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v6.0.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v6.0.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.35 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.34 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.33 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.32 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.31 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.30 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.29 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.28 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.27 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.24 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.22 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.20 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.19 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.18 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.17 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.15 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.14 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.12 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.11 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - illuminate/support v5.8.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/ui ^1.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v1.1.0, v1.1.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I have looked on the stackoverflow and stackexhange but their solutions didn't work for me.

Here is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your `composer.json` contents.

Comment: I have edited the question see it.

Comment: What is the PHP version?

Comment: Do you use Laravel 6.X?

Comment: PHP version is 7.2

Comment: I am using laravel 6.2 as you can see in composer.json file

Comment: btw Laravel 6.2 is Laravel 6 ... 6.2 is not a version onto itself

Comment: Hey Muhammad Ahmed, Last day i have same lines of warninngs and errors,I found that these things are by version mismatch. I had pasted package name directly in composer.json with Version 1.* and run composer update and its work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the idea from Jean Marcos Answer
First running the command

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-dom
```

Now, the command `composer require laravel/ui` worked fine

If this approach doesn't work. Try using this one

```
composer require laravel/ui:^2.4
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: What for windows?

Comment: @PriyankMotivaras Are you receiving the same error?

Comment: I think in  windows simply uncomment the line `extension = php_mbstring.dll;` by removing the semicolon in the end in your  php.ini file . And follow the same for other missing libraries( or whatever they are called).

Answer (score 2):

maybe you must use this instead

```
composer require laravel/ui:^2.4
```

Answer (score 2):

only `composer require laravel/ui` without any ui version is sufficient and automatically you'll get the required ui without any error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `mbstring` extension. You can intall on ubuntu for php 7.2 with:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring
```

Comment: Jean Marcos it is not working showing the same problems

Comment: Thanks Jean Marcos for giving the idea

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad upvote the answer if it help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have what I think is a similar issue:
I tried without versions, with versions. It keeps failing.

$ composer require laravel/ui:^2.4
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/ui
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/ui[v2.4.0, ..., v2.5.0] require illuminate/console ^7.0 -> found illuminate/console[v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/ui ^2.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.5.0].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31269345)

Answer (score 0):

hi programmer for laravel 8.* when i want to install laravel ui it gives me this error bellow =>
composer require laravel/ui
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^4.0 for laravel/ui
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/ui
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires laravel/ui ^4.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, 4.x-dev].
- laravel/ui[v4.0.0, ..., 4.x-dev] require illuminate/console ^9.21 -> found illuminate/console[v9.21.0, ..., 9.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because
it conflicts with another require.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/ui:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/ui:^2.1" if you know which you need.
i only resolved this error by running with this command :
composer require laravel/ui:*